# Manage emails via TXT file?

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have an email address that does some things when it receives an email from an org user.
I am trying to setup an SMTP server that automatically sends pre-formatted emails to this destination address whenever a PHP form is submitted.

The problem is that I don't know how I can get the destination email to "see" the inputted user's email in the 'from' header.

For reasons I won't go into, the PHP form actually creates a .txt file and a second process moves these files to the mailroot/Pickup dir for the server to send out. But I can only send emails if the 'from' header matches the authenticated account in my SMTP Server.

How can I use this workflow and have a different 'from' address? Is this possible?

Thank you!

Sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fetch Mail</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post">
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="textdata"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>


<?php        
if(isset($_POST['textdata']))
{
$email=$_POST['textdata'];

$fp = fopen('../../mailroot/Pickup/ticket.txt', 'wb');
$getName = $email;
$from = "From: email@domain.com\r\n";
$to = "To: $email\r\n";
$subject = "Email Subject\r\n\r\n"
$body = "This the body of the email\r\n"

fwrite($fp, $from, $to, $subject, $body);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Can the destination inbox be programmed to look in the Reply-To header as well, perhaps?

Comment: Whether or not this is possible depends completely on the mail host. You might work around this limitation by using Reply-To instead. (But note that, in this case, the emails will still have the authenticating address in the headers, which you may not want, especially if it's a personal account.) Alternatively, you might just skip your local server and send the Pickup messages via an email service like Mailgun.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions, @ADyson and @AlexHowansky!
But the 'reply-to' didn't work. Not even sure if this is possible, to be honest!

Comment: Well you mention that this email address "does things" when emails are received. How does it do them? Presumably it reads the address from the From field, among other things, since you talked about that. There must be some code or process or something to do it. If it can read from one header (the From header) it should be able to read from any other header too, if given the right instruction. It wasn't clear if you control that inbox and can re-program whatever is reading these emails you send?

Comment: I have a couple of different functions that parses through the data and looks for certain strings, and logs different things within different files. In some cases it also amends the txt file. When it's all 'done', the txt file is moved to the mailroot/Pickup folder and is sent on its way. There's probably a better way of doing it - I'm just new to SMTP servers and I'm taking steps towards incorporating my workflow into it. Thank you for your help :)